# Enrich my list from a key/values dictionnary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mapping

```html
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, city, country=""):
        self.name = name
        self.city = city
        self.country = country
    
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Person[' + self.name + "," + self.city + "," + self.country + ']'

cities_to_countries = {
      'Beijing': 'China',
      'London': 'United Kingdom',
      'San Francisco': 'United States',
      'Singapore': 'Singapore',
      'Sydney': 'Australia'
  }

persons = [
      Person('Henry', 'Singapore'),
      Person('Jane', 'San Francisco'),
      Person('Lee', 'Beijing'),
      Person('John', 'Sydney'),
      Person('Alfred', 'London')
  ]
```

Hey , i would like to add countries into my persons.country. For exemple i would like Jane to have San francisco as a city and United states as a country by matching my dictionary key/values and my list

Comment: Please update your question with a question.

Comment: And what about the case where a person has a city which doesn't match your `dict`?

Comment: suggestion: use `f strings` (if python >= 3.6) for example here: `f'Person[{self.name}, {self.city}, {self.country}]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over your persons list and set the persons countries using the city as the key in the dictionary:

```
for peep in persons:
    peep.country = cities_to_countries[peep.city]
```